# Dynamically Rename Column in the Post Admin Screen

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation, hook-wordpress

I am working dynamically renaming a column in the post admin screen. The code that I have so far is through the `manage_post_columns` hook:

```
function rename_columns ( $columns ){
  $columns ['author'] = 'Writer';
  return $columns;
}

add_filter ('manage_posts_columns', 'rename_columns', 30 );
```

So far, it is hard-coded with 'Writer' but I would like to make that to make that field dynamic. I have built a settings page on the backend to enter the code and the data is being stored in the database but I seem to be stuck on how to pull that data dynamically. I have tried so far:

```
function rename_columns ( $columns ){
  $options = get_option( 'renamer_settings' );
  $columns ['author'] = esc_html( $options['custom-text'] );
  return $columns;
}
add_filter ('manage_posts_columns', 'rename_columns', 30 );
```

I would be grateful for any pointers! Any ideas how to dynamically pull the data into that field?

Comment: Is the static 'Writer' working fine?

Comment: Yep, it does! It renames "Author" to "Writer" perfectly

Comment: That's mean your `$options = get_option( 'renamer_settings' );` code is not getting the data. kindly check if you are getting data.

Comment: I have made a bit more testing with this bit of code and was able to get the data into the admin footer so it seems that the data is going through but not in the post columns field. I am wondering if renaming that column can be potentially more complex. This is the code that I tested with:

Comment: function renamer_custom_admin_footer( $footer ) {

  $options = get_option( 'renamer_settings' );

  if( $options['custom_text'] ) {

    $footer_text = esc_html( $options['custom_text'] );
    return $footer_text;

  } else {

    return $footer;

  }


}
add_filter( 'admin_footer_text', 'renamer_custom_admin_footer', 10, 1 );
}
}